# How to Enable ZRAM on PC?

Tags: ram, zram

I am trying to know how to enable ZRAM for my PC running Ubuntu. I have heard that the ZRAM is speeding up some laptop and PCs, so will the ZRAM help My PC too?

PC specs:

```
CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo E4500 (2) @ 1.770GHz 
                    GPU: Intel 965Q 
                    Memory: 684MiB / 2992MiB
```

Can someone tell me how to enable ZRAM?

Comment: What are the two numbers for memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run `sudo apt-get install zram-config` and everything will be handled for you

After that if you need to customize the settings then you can use `zramctl` or write some options to `/dev/zramX`

Comment: You have any amount of ZRAM size reccomendations which will speed up My PC sir

Comment: Sir thank you for helping me and I appreciate you for anwering me

Comment: @RusevPutin just install `zram-config` and you don't need to care about anything else if you don't really know about zram. The size will be calculated automatically. You also don't need to disable swap partition/file if you already have, zram will have higher priority and normal swap so it'll be used first and when it's full then swap on disk will be used]

Comment: Please sir with all due respect.. Will this be able to fasten up the system ?

Comment: It depends. It'll be faster than swap on disk but don't expect it to be fast if you're really low on memory

Comment: What do you mean sir when you say " really low on memory"

Answer (score 1):

`zramctl --find -s 500M` - to create a 0.5GB ramdisk, but it doesn't speed up anything.

Comment: Wouldn't you also need to set the system up to use it after creating it?

Comment: Do you know the amount of ZRAM which will speed up the PC sir?

Comment: I have also heard that we also have to disable the swap before using ZRAM sir